# Live search django. How to search by key among first signs

Tags: django, search

I am trying to implement live search. As user types something in input that key is carried to django, and used in this line, found in docs:

```
 result = Event.objects.filter(title__contains=key)
```

But the problem is that result will be every title that contains the key(let's say user types a, and the results will be "hallo", "taro", "pam").But I obviously need to search only by first letters. So if the key is "az", it will only search words containing "az" as first two letters, not anywhere in word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [startswith](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/).

Try

```
    result = Event.objects.filter(title__startswith=key)
```

for case-sensitive search, or

```
    result = Event.objects.filter(title__istartswith=key)
```

for case-insensitive

Answer (score 0):

You can use [startswith](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-startswith), Django docs linked.

Example:

```
Entry.objects.filter(headline__startswith='Will')
```

Comment: hmm, somehow returns empty when it has not. Can it return nothing because of non english text and search key?

Comment: sorry, it works. just needed to use case-insensitive